# "management" is not a known member of module "arcpy" Pylance(report GeneralTypeIssues)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arcgis, arcpy, pylance

I am new to using vscode with python.exe for arcgispro. My interpreter is set to the `arcgispro-py3-env\python.exe`.

I would like to be able to run python code within vscode but I am running into some issues with pylance, which does not seem to recognize arcgis functions or able to set my working directory.

For example when I try to set my working directory to
`env.workspace = wd`

I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign member "workspace" for type "GPEnvironment" 
     Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues) Member "workspace" is unknown
```

Or when I try to execute the following
code `arcpy.management.Project`, I get the following error:

```
"management" is not a known member of module "arcpy" 
     Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

I don't want to use the `#type:ignore fix` as this will be cumbersome with lots of code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to avoid a Pylance error is to add `import arcpy.management`:

```py
import arcpy
import arcpy.management  # <- import arcpy.management explicitely

arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
     r"c:\temp", "buildings.shp", spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
```

The reason is most likely that `arcpy.management` is unkonwn to `arcpy/__ini__.py`.

As for `arcpy.env.workspace`, looking at the auto-completion, `arcpy.env` seems to be some sort of dictionary class:

[image]

With this knowledge, you could use the `[]` operator to avoid a Pylance error. For example:

```py
import arcpy
import arcpy.management

arcpy.env["overwriteOutput"] = True  # <- using [] operator instead

arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(
     r"c:\temp", "buildings.shp", spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
```

Comment: That's certainly the easiest way, I'm curious if there's some additional settings that might tell VS Code/Pylance to automatically import arcpy.management for the purposes of its type checking and code completion